# “Спелый мой” – what does it mean?

Tags: перевод, значения

Слава has [this song Спелый мой](https://youtu.be/tqhVCmc_sic), but I can't find any translation that makes any sense to me.

Here's the lyrics:

> Спелый мой, нежно целуй подолгу,
>   Зрелый мой, плечи ласкай ладонью,
>   Вкусный мой, в сердце оставь наколку.
>   Дорогой, слезы — любви подспорье.
>
> Спелый мой, я не живу — я плачу,
>   Зрелый мой, я не могу иначе.
>   Вкусный мой, чувства мои незрячи,
>   Мой родной.

I found this, but it does not make sense in the context of the song:

> спелый
>   1. mature
>   спелый лес — mature forest
>   спелый шлак — matured slag
>   спелый ячмень — mature barley
>   спелое лесонасаждение — mature forest stand
>   2. mellow
>   спелый солод — mellow malt
>   спелое зерно — mellow grain
>   3. ripe
>   спелое яблоко — ripe apple
>   спелое зерно — ripe grain
>   спелая древесина — ripe wood

Comment: Eww, guy. You're trying to analyze something that probably came from lyrics-writing machine a-la 1984.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meaning of the word is "ripe".

The narrator compares her beloved one to a ripe fruit and calls him *спелый* ("ripe"), *зрелый* ("mature", meaning both "adult" and "fully developed", just like the English term); and *вкусный* ("tasty").

The song is full of masochistic innuendos and the author hints at her being blind (probably because of being blindfolded), so apparently she wants to state the fact that sense of taste is the only way she could feel her partner.

Comment: "Hints at her being blind" — how? where? Sounds like extreme overanalysing to me.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov "чувства мои незрячи"

Comment: Maybe "Чувства мои незрячи" means just "любовь слепа"?

Comment: I'm puzzled with "глаза мои безбрежны". Is it about endless crying? Or about blindness and limitless inner vision (a very popular metaphor since Ancient Greece)?

Comment: @Artemix: maybe. Actually feel free to ignore, agree with or disagree with the rest of the answer, it's hardly a place to analyze lyrics of a pop song.

Comment: @EugeniaVlasova I think "безбрежные" is variation of "бездонные глаза".

Answer (score 3):

You are right in that the word *спелый* does not make a lot of sense here. It's pretty much dragged in by the heels in line with the lamentable pretentiousness and cheesiness of these lyrics.

Given the undoubted sexual whiff of the lyrics, one could argue that *спелый* here is borrowed from the colloquial expression *спелая девушка* or *спелая женщина* -- a very low-key term for a sexually attractive and presumably available young female. The lyrics is a good example of a cheap-night-club Russian.

Comment: Just after posting this I thought that somebody was going to tell me that it has to do with спел — singing of some sort?

Comment: @Johan: *спел* (singular masculine past form of the perfective verb *спеть*, "to have sung") and *спел* (short form of the adjective *спелый*, "ripe") are homonyms in Russian. The first meaning has absolutely nothing to do with the song, not even remotely.