# Что значит выражение "Не попадись под ключ,"?

Tags: лексикон

Вперёд, болты! (Ноль) Федор Чистяков

http://www.falshivim-vmeste.ru/songs/1177891200.html

```
Не попадись под ключ,
 Сегодня нервы сдвинуты.
```

Значит ли это некий вирусный штамм?

Answer (score 2):

See [попасть под горячую руку](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D1%83%D1%8E_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83). So here it means *watch out to not get hit by the wrench*.

The text seems to have a sexual implication, but I'm not sure if the wrench has something to do with it.

Comment: ни разу не слышал, что бы "руку" заменяли чем-либо в этом выражении.

Comment: @anonymous Наверное, стоит обобщить, что _попасть под что-либо_ - это получить травму, неприятности: попасть под дождь, попасть под удар. В этом конкретном случае мне показалось, что будет удобно провести именно такую аналогию.

Comment: @anonymous Текст поэтический, поэтому можно всякого ожидать. Вот здесь вообще заменяют все подряд: http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/8208/551

Answer (score 1):

`Под ключ` is an [idiom](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87) that gets a lot of "commercialese" usage (in real estate ads, etc.); `закручивать болты` — or more commonly, `закручивать гайки` — has, in its turn, been a political buzzphrase since about the mid-2000s, so the whole thing sounds like vague and obviously innuendo-tinged attempts at puns based on two common and somewhat annoyingly hackneyed expressions. They weren't meant to make a terrible amount of literal sense, or have any particularly nuanced subtexts. Just contemporary Russian songwriting being the glorified madlibs it so often is.

EDIT: sorry, my conjectures are completely anachronistic, it's a 1989 song, and that band is *all about* unsubtle innuendo. Let this be a lesson.

Comment: I always thought *закручивать болты* was a calque from English "to screw", with the same meaning.

Comment: Энивэй, интересный взгляд с "закручиванием гаек".

Answer (score 0):

In this context it's clearly sexual:

```
Сегодня мы ждем:
К нам придут герлы.
Сегодня мы не спим:
К нам придут герлы.
Мы будем вместе с ними закручивать болты,
...
Не попадись под ключ
```

Rough translation (not poetic) looks like:

```
Today we're waiting
Girls coming
Today we don't sleep:
Girls coming
Together we'll twist bolts
...
Don't be caught by wrench
```

I think with this translation everything is clear enough :)

Comment: зачем ты переводишь песню на английских? Этот SE - для русского языка.

Comment: Ты уверен? Это SE для иностранцев изучающих английский:

>>Russian Language and Usage is a question and answer site 
>>for people who are interested in studying or teaching >>Russian

Answer (score -1):

I never heard or read such expression in Russian, probably there is no such expression.  But `гeрлы` is colloqual for girls. Therefore, `закручивать болты` (to screw bolts) refers to sex. `Ключ` is probably an allusion to the famous poem "Дебют" by Joseph Brodsky:

```
Сдав все свои экзамены, она
к себе в субботу пригласила друга,
был вечер, и закупорена туго
была бутылка красного вина.

А воскресенье началось с дождя,
и гость, на цыпочках прокравшись между
скрипучих стульев, снял свою одежду
с непрочно в стену вбитого гвоздя.

Она достала чашку со стола
и выплеснула в рот остатки чая.
Квартира в этот час еще спала.
Она лежала в ванне, ощущая

всей кожей облупившееся дно,
и пустота, благоухая мылом,
ползла в нее через еще одно
отверстие, знакомящее с миром.

2

Дверь тихо притворившая рука
была -- он вздрогнул -- выпачкана; пряча
ее в карман, он услыхал, как сдача
с вина плеснула в недрах пиджака.

Проспект был пуст. Из водосточных труб
лилась вода, сметавшая окурки.
Он вспомнил гвоздь и струйку штукатурки,
и почему-то вдруг с набрякших губ

сорвалось слово (Боже упаси
от всякого его запечатленья),
и если б тут не подошло такси,
остолбенел бы он от изумленья.

Он раздевался в комнате своей,
не глядя на припахивавший потом
ключ, подходящий к множеству дверей,
ошеломленный первым оборотом.
```

Comment: это разве ответ? я знаю что герлы - это девушки, чувихи, вопрос был - что такое ключ в данном контексте?

Comment: Что такое ключ, я написал. Если вы не умеете читать, ваши проблемы.